# Changing direction of menuItems arrow icon on click in R shinydashboard

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

In the example below, is there anyway to make the sidebar's left-facing arrow point down when not selected (indicating that clicking it would open the menu) and up when selected (indicating that it can be closed)?

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(
      menuItem(text = "Click Me!",
               "Hello World!")
    )
  ),
  dashboardBody()
)

server <- function(input, output) { }

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

My desired end result would thus be:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achive this via `shinyjs`:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)
library(htmltools)
library(shinydashboard)

sidebar <- htmltools::tagQuery(dashboardSidebar(
  sidebarMenu(
    id = "sidebarID",
    menuItem(text = "Click Me!",
             "Hello World!")
  )
))

sidebar <- sidebar$find("i")$removeClass("fa-angle-left")$addClass("fa-angle-down")$allTags()

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  sidebar,
  dashboardBody(
    useShinyjs()
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  observeEvent(input$sidebarItemExpanded, {
    if(!is.null(input$sidebarItemExpanded)){
      removeCssClass(class = "fa-angle-down", selector = "#sidebarItemExpanded > ul > li > a > i")
      addCssClass(class = "fa-angle-up", selector = "#sidebarItemExpanded > ul > li > a > i")
    } else {
      addCssClass(class = "fa-angle-down", selector = "#sidebarItemExpanded > ul > li > a > i")
      removeCssClass(class = "fa-angle-up", selector = "#sidebarItemExpanded > ul > li > a > i")
    }
  }, ignoreNULL = FALSE)
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

---

**Edit:** for multiple menuItems:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)
library(htmltools)
library(shinydashboard)

sidebar <- htmltools::tagQuery(dashboardSidebar(
  sidebarMenu(
    id = "sidebarID",
    menuItem(text = "Click Me!",
             "Hello World!"),
    menuItem(text = "or click Me!",
             "Hello World!")
  )
))

sidebar <- sidebar$find("i")$removeClass("fa-angle-left")$addClass("fa-angle-down")$allTags()

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  sidebar,
  dashboardBody()
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  previousSelection <- reactiveVal(isolate(input$sidebarItemExpanded))
  observeEvent(input$sidebarItemExpanded, {
    if(!is.null(input$sidebarItemExpanded)){
      removeCssClass(class = "fa-angle-down", selector = "#sidebarItemExpanded > ul > li.treeview.active > a > i")
      addCssClass(class = "fa-angle-up", selector = "#sidebarItemExpanded > ul > li.treeview.active > a > i")
      
      if(!is.null(previousSelection())){
        if(input$sidebarItemExpanded != previousSelection()){
          addCssClass(class = "fa-angle-down", selector = "#sidebarItemExpanded > ul > li > a > i")
          removeCssClass(class = "fa-angle-up", selector = "#sidebarItemExpanded > ul > li > a > i")
          removeCssClass(class = "fa-angle-down", selector = "#sidebarItemExpanded > ul > li.treeview.active > a > i")
          addCssClass(class = "fa-angle-up", selector = "#sidebarItemExpanded > ul > li.treeview.active > a > i")
        }
      }

      previousSelection(input$sidebarItemExpanded)
      
    } else {
      addCssClass(class = "fa-angle-down", selector = "#sidebarItemExpanded > ul > li > a > i")
      removeCssClass(class = "fa-angle-up", selector = "#sidebarItemExpanded > ul > li > a > i")
    }
  }, ignoreNULL = FALSE)
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thanks @ismirsehregal. Question - what version of `htmltools` are you running? I tried using your code, but I don't see `tagQuery` as a package function. I'm running 0.5.1.1

Comment: Hi @DJC - I'm using htmltools v. 0.5.2 (latest CRAN) - [here](https://rstudio.github.io/htmltools/articles/tagQuery.html) you can find related information.

Comment: one more question which I recognize is outside of the scope of the original question. Is there any easy way to tweak this to have the arrows act independently w/ multiple menu items:

sidebar <- htmltools::tagQuery(dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(
      id = "sidebarID1",
      menuItem(text = "Click Me!",
               "Hello World!")
    ),
    sidebarMenu(
      id = "sidebarID2",
      menuItem(text = "Click Me Again!",
               "Hello World!")
    )
))

Also no worries if this is prohibitively complicated

Comment: @DJC Please see my edit. In the end I'm not too happy with the `shinyjs` solution. It always has the drawback of taking a detour to the server. Solving this on the client side (UI only) would be more elegant and faster but my JS skills are quite limited.

Comment: Gotcha. That makes sense. Thanks very much for your help as always!